# FFmpeg to rotate video if necessary, and overlay png

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am trying to write a script that can accept videos of arbitrary orientation, use FFmpeg to detect the orientation, then overlay a logo in the correct way in the bottom right corner of the screen.

This script is working for landscape mode:

```
import subprocess
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, ImageClip

def is_video_portrait(video_path):
    video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
    return video_clip.size[1] > video_clip.size[0]  # True if portrait

def transpose_video(video_path, output_path):
    subprocess.run(['/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', video_path, '-vf', 'transpose=2', '-c:a', 'copy', output_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

def overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path):
    logo_clip = ImageClip(image_path).set_duration(video_clip.duration)
    logo_position = (video_clip.size[0] - logo_clip.size[0], video_clip.size[1] - logo_clip.size[1])  # Bottom right
    return CompositeVideoClip([video_clip, logo_clip.set_position(logo_position)], size=video_clip.size)

def overlay_image_on_video(video_path, image_path, output_path):
    if is_video_portrait(video_path):
        # Process for portrait videos
        transposed_path = "transposed_" + video_path
        transpose_video(video_path, transposed_path)
        video_clip = VideoFileClip(transposed_path)
        final_clip = overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path)
        temp_output_path = "temp_" + output_path
        final_clip.write_videofile(temp_output_path, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac')
        transpose_video(temp_output_path, output_path)
        subprocess.call(['rm', transposed_path, temp_output_path])  # Remove temporary files
    else:
        # Process for landscape videos
        video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
        final_clip = overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path)
        final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac')

# Example usage
overlay_image_on_video("cat.mov", "logo.png", "output_video.mp4")
```

Example output:

[image]

But when I give it a video shot in portrait mode - screenshot example:
[image]

It gives me an output that is flipped to landscape -- and thus distorted!

[image]

I want to detect the orientation of the video, if it is shot in portrait, to rotate the logo appropriately (e.g. -90 degrees) and stick it in the top right corner.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Tried this and got the same result:

```
import subprocess
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, ImageClip

def get_orientation(size):
    return "Portrait" if size[1] > size[0] else "Landscape"

def overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path):
    logo_clip = ImageClip(image_path).set_duration(video_clip.duration)
    logo_position = (video_clip.size[0] - logo_clip.size[0], video_clip.size[1] - logo_clip.size[1])  # Bottom right
    print(f"Placing logo at position: {logo_position}")
    return CompositeVideoClip([video_clip, logo_clip.set_position(logo_position)], size=video_clip.size)

def overlay_image_on_video(video_path, image_path, output_path):
    video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
    print(f"Original video '{video_path}' size: {video_clip.size}, Orientation: {get_orientation(video_clip.size)}")

    # Check if video is rotated and resize if necessary
    if video_clip.rotation == 90:
        video_clip = video_clip.resize(video_clip.size[::-1])
        video_clip.rotation = 0
        print(f"Video '{video_path}' was rotated. Adjusted size: {video_clip.size}, Orientation: {get_orientation(video_clip.size)}")

    final_clip = overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path)
    final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac')

# Example usage
overlay_image_on_video("cat.mov", "logo.png", "output_video.mp4")
```

Edit2:
Tried this as well with the same result:

```
import subprocess
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, CompositeVideoClip, ImageClip

def get_orientation(size):
    return "Portrait" if size[1] > size[0] else "Landscape"

def overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path):
    logo_clip = ImageClip(image_path).set_duration(video_clip.duration)
    logo_position = (video_clip.size[0] - logo_clip.size[0], video_clip.size[1] - logo_clip.size[1])  # Bottom right
    print(f"Placing logo at position: {logo_position}")
    return CompositeVideoClip([video_clip, logo_clip.set_position(logo_position)], size=video_clip.size)

def overlay_image_on_video(video_path, image_path, output_path):
    video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
    original_orientation = get_orientation(video_clip.size)
    print(f"Original video '{video_path}' size: {video_clip.size}, Orientation: {original_orientation}")

    # Check if video is rotated and resize if necessary
    if video_clip.rotation == 90:
        video_clip = video_clip.resize(video_clip.size[::-1])
        video_clip.rotation = 0
        adjusted_orientation = get_orientation(video_clip.size)
        print(f"Video '{video_path}' was rotated. Adjusted size: {video_clip.size}, Orientation: {adjusted_orientation}")

    final_clip = overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path)
    final_clip.write_videofile(output_path, codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac')

# Example usage
overlay_image_on_video("cat2.mov", "logo.png", "output_video.mp4")
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I see you already use `width < height` to detect `portrait mode` - so you have to check if you use correct values for this mode when you convert it. Use `print()` for this.

Comment: [moviepy.video.fx.all.rotate — MoviePy 1.0.2 documentation](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.rotate.html)

Comment: @furas - thanks - the print statements showed me that it's incorrectly detecting the input videos as landscape mode even when they are portrait. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: many phones and cameras write all images as `landscape` JPG and set special flag in file  to inform that it has to be treated as `portrait` image - and later some programs has problem to recognize it in correct way - but I never met this problem with video. In some other question on Stackoverflow I saw code which uses `ffproble` to get corect size. maybe it can help. I don't have videos with this problem to check how it works

Comment: searching `moviepy video wrong orientation` in `Google` I found [Portrait videos converted to landscape on load · Issue #586 · Zulko/moviepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/586) and it suggests that MoviePy may rotate image and set `video.rotation = 90` and you have to check `if video.rotation == 90:`

Comment: @furas - thanks - i just tried that and am getting the same results... not sure what to try next

Comment: it seems there are two problems. First to detect portrait orientation (and it should resolve code in my answer). Second to fix it correctly. And second problem makes still problem. When I test `resize(video_clip.size[::-1])` and `rotation = 0` and save it then I get correct result. But I didn't test it with `overlay_logo`

Answer (score 1):

Some cameras write always landscape video
but they add tag `Rotation=90`
to inform other programs that they should rotate frames before displaying or editing.

And it seems `MoviePy` gives original landscape size
and you have to also check if `clip.rotation` is `90` or `270`.

Tag `Rotation` may have values: `0`, `90`, `180`, `270`.

Code may need

```
def is_video_portrait(video_clip):
    width, height = video_clip.size
    
    if video_clip.rotation in (90, 270):
       return width > height
    else:
       return height > width
```

As for fixing rotation I found code in `issues` in `MoviePy's GitHub`
[Portrait videos converted to landscape on load · Issue #586 · Zulko/moviepy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/586)

```
def fix_rotation(video_clip):
    if video_clip.rotation in (90, 270):
        video_clip = video_clip.resize(video_clip.size[::-1])
        video_clip.rotation = 0
    return video_clip
```

---

I tested it on normal `landscape` video, a `portrait` video created with `exiftool`

```
cp video_landscape.mp4 video_portrait.mp4
exiftool -Rotation=90 video_portrait.mp4
```

And with some `png` as logo.

Full code used for tests:

```
from moviepy.editor import *


def is_video_portrait(video_clip):
    width, height = video_clip.size
    
    if video_clip.rotation in (90, 270):
       return width > height
    else:
       return height > width


def fix_rotation(video_clip):
    if video_clip.rotation in (90, 270):
        video_clip = video_clip.resize(video_clip.size[::-1])
        video_clip.rotation = 0
    return video_clip


def overlay_logo(video_clip, image_path):
    logo_clip = ImageClip(image_path).set_duration(video_clip.duration)
    
    logo_w, logo_h = logo_clip.size
    video_w, video_h = video_clip.size
    
    logo_position = (video_w - logo_w, video_h - logo_h)  # Bottom right
    logo_clip = logo_clip.set_position(logo_position)
    
    print(f"Placing logo at position: {logo_position}")
    
    return CompositeVideoClip([video_clip, logo_clip], size=video_clip.size)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logo_path = 'logo-F-32.png'
    
    all_video_paths = ['video_landscape.MP4', 'video_portrait.MP4']
    
    for video_path in all_video_paths:
    
        print(f'===== {video_path} =====')

        video_clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)

        print(f'[BEFORE] portrait:', is_video_portrait(video_clip), '| Size:', video_clip.size, '| Rotation:', video_clip.rotation)

        video_clip = fix_rotation(video_clip)

        print(f'[AFTER ] portrait:', is_video_portrait(video_clip), '| Size:', video_clip.size, '| Rotation:', video_clip.rotation)
        
        final_clip = overlay_logo(video_clip, logo_path)
        
        final_clip.write_videofile(f'rotated_{video_path}')
```

Comment: I just tried that (and another version -- see the two edits appended to the bottom of my original post). I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I tested `resize(video_clip.size[::-1])` and `rotation = 0` (and overlaying logo) with own files and it works. I put full code which I used for tests. If you have still problem then you may need to show your example video. Maybe there is something else in your video file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to rotate a video using FFMPEG.
Try using the 'vf' (video filter) option.

One way is to use the 'rotate': https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate
Another way using transpose: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1

> ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -qscale 1 -vf "transpose=1" output.avi

Transpose arguments:
0 - 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 - 90Clockwise
2 - 90CounterClockwise
3 - 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip

In Python:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
fileName = "test.avi"
subprocess.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg.exe -i {fileName} -qscale 1 -vf "transpose=1" output.avi'))
```